# Test set accuracy of simple Tensorflow CNN segmentation is low

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

I modified the https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros/ to pose it as an image segmentation, rather than a classification problem. The inputs are 60x60 downsampled MRI images (reshaped to [1,3600]) and the outputs are segmentations with 0 to 1 range (thresholded at 0.5 to binary masks). When I run it, I get very reasonable segmentations and a high dice (0.99) in the training set. However, the test set only reaches a dice of 0.8. This sounds like overfitting but the model is super simple: conv layer-max pool-conv layer-dropout-prediction. So, there are only 3 sets of weights and biases, and I am not sure over-complexity is the problem. For regularization I am using dropout rate of 10%. I tried dropout of 50%, and also L1-norm regularization - it hasn't made a difference. I originally used 300 images for the training set and 184 for the test set. Went up to 740-740 and it hasn't made a difference. The test set's dice is insisting on being 0.8, almost exactly. When I run the code pretending training data is test data, I get nearly identical (but not absolutely identical) dices. I would greatly appreciate your suggestions.

```
W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)

# Pooling layer - downsamples by 2X.
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

# Second convolutional layer -- maps 32 feature maps to 64.
W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])
h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)

# Second pooling layer.
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

# Fully connected layer 1 -- after 2 round of downsampling, our 28x28 image
# is down to 7x7x64 feature maps -- maps this to 1024 features.
W_fc1 = weight_variable([15 * 15 * 64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 15*15*64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

# Dropout - controls the complexity of the model, prevents co-adaptation of
# features.
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

# Map the 1024 features to 10 classes, one for each digit
W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 3600])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([3600])

y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2
```

P.S.:  My loss function is mean squared differences tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_mean(tf.multiply(y_-y_conv,y_-y_conv))), not dice explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Overfitting indeed: if you'd like to compare number of training examples and number of parameters, number of parameters is far more than number of examples. However, even overfitting, I don't think dice 0.8 is low.

Suggestions: you may want to know Fully Convolutional Networks ([FCN](http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2015/papers/Long_Fully_Convolutional_Networks_2015_CVPR_paper.pdf)).

Comment: I see the point that this works out to something like 14 million parameters, mainly in the conv2-fc and fc to output connections. It seems most CNN's use more features and fewer training images, though (e.g. Large scale tissue histopathology image classification, segmentation, and visualization via deep convolutional activation features. Dice = 0.97). So orders of magnitude fewer parameters than examples. Any suggestions? Dice of 0.8 isn't that bad but that's the average and in some images it goes down to 0.5. I have a non-CNN segmentation that does much better.

Comment: For reducing parameters, FCN can be considered. For avoid overfitting, fine-tuning from a pre-trained model and techniques of data augmentation can help a lot. In the case of segmentation, using bigger images may help too.